# A program with passing arguments, Why this program has wrong answer?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, arguments, parameter-passing

I have learned something about how we can pass arguments to a program. 
My homework is finding result when we add, subtract, multiply, divide 2 number by passing the program arguments. 
My code is here (I use Visual Studio 2017)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    if (argc != 4) {
        printf("Wrong argument !");
    }
    else {
        int a = atoi(argv[1]);
        int b = atoi(argv[3]);
        if (argv[2][0] == '+') {
            printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a + b);
            return 0;
        }
        if (argv[2][0] == '-') {
            printf("%d - %d = %d\n", a, b, a - b);
            return 0;
        }
        if (argv[2][0] == '*') {
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n", a, b, a * b);
            return 0;
        }
        if (argv[2][0] == '/') {
            printf("%d / %d = %f\n", a, b, (float) a/ b);
            return 0;
        }
        printf("No available operator!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When i pass arguments 2 + 3. The result is 5.
When i pass a wrong operator, such as 2 ^ 3. The answer is "Wrong argument !".
I have debugged the program a few times, they printed "No available operator!", but it always went back to the first line and could not end the program.
Could you explain me this situation ?

Comment: when the desired operation is 'divide', be sure to check that variable 'b' is NOT 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that `CMD.exe` treats the `^` as an escape character that has special meaning on the command line, so I don't think that character is even making it to your program.

I would try passing:

```
myprogram.exe 2 ^^ 3
```

to escape the escape character.

Comment: Related: [Windows CMD Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)